# How to declare an Object with unknown key (UUID) in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, object, key, uuid

I'm learning Typescript. I would like to know how I could declare an unknown key of an Object (which is an UUID: I don't know the value in advance) and also, how to declare that I need several Objects (equivalent to an Array: "**employees: Person[]**"). For example, in JSON, I have:

```
let employees = {
   "5175d6f8-009f-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002": {
      name: "John",
      age: 23
   },
   "04c6dcc5-0442-4858-875d-695d4e933da2": {
      name: "Sophie",
      age: 30
   }
}
```

How could I declare this structure in Typescript? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: type Employees = { [key: string]: { name: string; age: number; } };

Comment: @theJian *theJian* - Thank you for your answer. That will help me to move forward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [index type signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures) and define type like this

```js
type Employee = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

type Employees = {
  [key: string]: Employee
}
```

Comment: *Pritam Kadam* - As a beginner, I thought that I have to use "interface". Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you can also use utility type [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)

```
type Employee = {
   name: string
   age: number
}

type Employees = Record<string, Employee>
```

Comment: *Miro* - I'm trying to add Typescript into my project (React-Redux, fullstack). Thank you for introducing me into "**Record**".